# Error: Failed to send Target is not set or not in URL format(Microsoft Teams)

Tags: office365connectors

```
"potentialAction": [
            {
                "@type": "HttpPOST",
                "name": "Renew",
                "targets": "url" 
            }
```

I am trying to do a HttpPost action thru connector cards in Microsoft Teams, But whenever I click the action button I get an error as "Failed to send  Target is not set or not in URL format". Can Someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "target" instead of "targets" for this. Please try with the following payload and it should work:

```
"potentialAction": [{
    "@type": "HttpPOST",
    "name": "Submit",
    "target": "https:// ..."
}]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to it, My mistake. ThankYou!